# Решение СЛАУ методом Гаусса по прямому и обратному ходам

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема. Мне нужно написать программу, которая решает СЛАУ методом Гаусса. Программа у меня работает, но не все написано, я не знаю, что там надо дописать. Программа должна  работать по прямому ходу (приведение расширенной матрицы до треугольного вида) и по обратному ходу (нахождение неизвестных). Помогите, пожалуйста.
Текст программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 50

void glavelem(int k, double mas[][N + 1], int n, int otv[]);

int main(void)
{
    double mas[N][N + 1];
    double x[N];                //корни системы
    int otv[N];                 //отвечает за порядок корней
    int i, j, k, n;
    //ввод данных
    //clrscr();
    do {
        printf("введите число уравнений сисемы: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (N < n)
            printf("слишком большое число уравнений, повторите ввод\n");
    }
    while (N < n);
    printf("введите систему:n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
            scanf("%lf", &mas[i][j]);
    //вывод введенной системы
    //clrscr();
    printf("система:n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
            printf("%7.2f ", mas[i][j]);
        printf("n");
    }
    //сначало все корни по порядку
    for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        otv[i] = i;
    //прямой ход метода Гаусса
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        glavelem(k, mas, n, otv);
        if (fabs(mas[k][k]) < 0.0001) {
            printf("система не имеет единственного решения");
            return (0);
        }
        for (j = n; j >= k; j--)
            mas[k][j] /= mas[k][k];
        for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
            for (j = n; j >= k; j--)
                mas[i][j] -= mas[k][j] * mas[i][k];
    }
    //обратных ход
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i] = mas[i][n];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            x[i] -= x[j] * mas[i][j];
    //вывод результата
    printf("Îòâåò:n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (i == otv[j]) {        //расставляем корни по порядку
                printf("%fn", x[j]);
                break;
            }
    return (0);
}

//----------------------------------------------
// описание функции
//----------------------------------------------
void glavelem(int k, double mas[][N + 1], int n, int otv[])
{
    int i, j, i_max = k, j_max = k;
    double temp;
    //ищем максимальный по модулю элемент
    for (i = k; i < n; i++)
        for (j = k; j < n; j++)
            if (fabs(mas[i_max][j_max]) < fabs(mas[i][j])) {
                i_max = i;
                j_max = j;
            }
    //переставляем строки
    for (j = k; j < n + 1; j++) {
        temp = mas[k][j];
        mas[k][j] = mas[i_max][j];
        mas[i_max][j] = temp;
    }
    //переставляем столбцы
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = mas[i][k];
        mas[i][k] = mas[i][j_max];
        mas[i][j_max] = temp;
    }
    //учитываем изменение порядка корней
    i = otv[k];
    otv[k] = otv[j_max];
    otv[j_max] = i;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Когда программа скомпилировалась, он дает ввести только сколько уранений в системе и саму системы, и он показывает какая матрица будет, и все потом он ничего не делает

Comment: 15,7x+6,6y-5,7z+11,5w= -2,4;
 8,8x-6,7y+5,5z-4,5w=5,6;
 6,3x-5,7y-23,4z+6,6w=7,7;
 14,3x+8,7y-15,7z-5,8w= 23,4;
 Скажем, нужно решить вот такую стстему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в конце функции glavelem стоит getch(). т.е. при каждой итерации программа ждет нажатия любой клавиши. Это сделано видимо для отладки. Уберите этот вызов из функции. Можете поставить в конец main перед строчкой return(0)

Answer (score 3):

1. Вполне достаточно искать главную строку с максимальным по модулю диагональным элементом, и где-то я читал, что достаточно найти ее ОДИН РАЗ.
2. Было бы полезно во время прямого хода заодно вычислять детерминант, который равен произведению диагональных элементов на каждой итерации.
3. Размеры матрицы следовало бы назначать динамически: во-первых, для экономии памяти; во-вторых, для красоты слога.
4. Строки следует переставлять не поэлементно, а адресами.
5. Не следует пользоваться глобальными переменными для переменных цикла. Запутаетесь и собьетесь. Здесь, на форуме, были тому примеры и, именно, с методом Гаусса.
6. Как у Вас написан обратный ход? я не понял, по правде говоря:

> ```
> for(int i = line - 1; i >= 0; i--)//Начало обратного хода
> {
>   double s = 0.0;
>   for(int j = line - 1; j > i; j--)
>     s += r[j] * temp[i][j];
>   r[i] = temp[i][line] - s;
> }//Конец обратного хода
> ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.